stability of rank one perturbation of stochastic matrix
Let $I$ be the identity matrix and $P$ be an irreducible $n$ by $n$ row stochastic matrix. Let $d$ be a stochastic (column) vector and $e$ be an all one (column) vector. Let $t > 0$ be a real number. Define $$A(t) = \rho(P)I - P + t de^\top,$$ where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of $P$. Since $P$ is stochastic, we know $\rho(P) = 1$. This $A(t)$ is then a rank one perturbation of the matrix $I - P$. Can we prove that $A(t)$ is positive stable for any $t > 0$, i.e., the real part of eigenvalues of $A(t)$ is strictly positive? The best result I can find is https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.11453. It provides counterexamples if $P$ is merely irreducible and nonnegative and their $d$ and $e$ are (almost) two arbitrary nonnegative vectors. I'm wondering by adding that the row sum of $P$ is 1 and more restrictions on $d$ and $e$, can we prove it? I tried to play with their counterexample but wasn't able to get a new counterexample under the stronger assumptions. If $d$ was the right eigenvector of $P$ or $e$ was the left eigenvector of $P$, things would be obvious according the references therein.
